# The Recycle Bin on E:\ is corrupted.Do you want to empty the Recycle Bin for this device?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, recycle-bin

I have formatted my system. Since then, I am getting this warning:

> The Recycle Bin on E:\ is corrupted.Do you want to empty the Recycle Bin for this device?

[image: Issue demonstration Image]

The drive in the picture is an external hard disk, and I am afraid to press yes as this might delete my whole data.

How to get rid of this irritating warning w/o loosing data.

Answer (score 0):

If you no longer need the content of Recycle bin, close that window, start a command prompt with administrator privileges and type

```
del "C:\$Recycle.Bin\*.*" /s /f /q /a
```

Then run a scandisk utility to repair any problems.

Comment: Thanks. This is the scan disk utility you are talking about → https://hard-drive-scandisk-pro.en.softonic.com/

Comment: The windows provided one should do for any basics. Click on the drive --> properties --> tools --> check now.

Answer (score 0):

Your fear is irrational.

Click "Yes". I have done this myriads of times. You risk losing your recycling functionality if you don't.

Then, proceed to delete all vestiges of `$Recycle.Bin` folder from your external hard drive.